# SSD transfer to another computer

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, operating-systems

I have an SSD disk that includes Windows 10 OS, installed programs and personal files which seems to work fine that I wish to transfer to another physical machine.

Note that I could easily physically transfer this SSD disk to other computers (either desktop or laptop) and everything is fine (just connect/disconnect two wires).

I recently purchased a computer that is more powerful which also works fine, but I wanted to remove the SSD disk from this machine and install my own previously mentioned drive that contains the OS, files, etc.

The following issues arise after physically swapping out the SSD:

> boot device could not found, please install an OS

In an attempt to fix this I went into BIOS mode and discovered that my SSD drive does not appear in the boot order listing. I unchecked boot order options and restarted the machine, however the result is the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: could it be a CSM/EFI thing? Like is one computer using EFI mode boot (probably the wrong phrase there) and the other using Legacy or CSM mode?

Comment: SSD is too vague, could be SATA, m.2 SATA, NVMe, some of which mobo may or may not support etc.. So you need to provide much more specific info & data. Without it 'suggestions' wil be wild guesses.

Comment: Go into the BIOS and disable secure boot, or anything like that.  Try legacy mode or CSM.

Answer (score 2):

Your old computers likely used BIOS firmware or were set up with CSM (Compatibility Support Module) enabled which emulates BIOS on newer UEFI based systems.

BIOS requires an MBR partitioned disk.

Your newer computer likely uses UEFI as the system firmware and may have removed CSM legacy BIOS support.

UEFI only supports booting from GPT partitioned disks.

You will have to convert your disk from the old style MBR to newer GPT. Be aware that this change is one-way and will mean that you have to reinstall Windows properly if you take that SSD to an older machine.

Intel have a guide at [How to Convert the System from Legacy BIOS mode to UEFI mode after Installing Windows](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000024558/memory-and-storage/intel-optane-memory.html)

There are a lot of words on that page that go into checking that your system actually has an MBR disk and that ***you should always make sure you have a good backup before proceeding*** but the general process is only 4 steps.

> 1. Open Command Prompt with administrator privileges.
> 2. Run the following command: `mbr2gpt.exe /convert /allowfullOS`
> 3. Restart the system and boot into the system BIOS.
> 4. Change the settings from Legacy BIOS mode to UEFI mode.

You will need to run steps 1 and 2 on the machine that this disk came out of. Then replace step 3 and 4 with putting the drive into the new machine.

But, this needs to be said, some things **can** go wrong. It being relatively simple is no excuse for not having a good backup.

It may still be that Windows will not boot properly, or will crash and require you to reinstall properly as the hardware platforms are just too different.